# How was the Black Bull squad ranked at the beginning of the Black Clover anime?

Tags: black-clover

At the begining of the anime, it is stated that Golden Dawn and Silver Eagle are the best squads. However, in the wikia,

> It is shown that Black Bull is the second squad with more stars

This makes me conclude they progressed as the story advanced. How was the Black Bull squad ranked at the begining of the anime among of the other squads?

Comment: It was Last with -31 stars in the beginning.

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore If you have the source for the numbers, it might be worth posting your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Black Bull is last in ranking in terms of the number of stars they have gathered**

The fist time they talked about how many stars the black bull have is after Asta and Noelle's first mission. The Black Bull have -31 stars while Golden Dawn have 70 stars at that time.

> Asta and Noelle earned a star for their first mission making it -30 stars for the Black Bull
>  [image: Black Bulls -30 stars]

---

The first time we see the full ranking of the nine magic knights squads is they are at the bottom though this is the last year's ranking. *Based on what Yami said, Black Bull is always last in the rankings of previous years.*

> Yami: Man.. What a pain in the butt. Were always last anyway.

---

> [image: Black Bull at the bottom]

---

Sources: Black Clover: Chapter 10 and Chapter 102 for pictures respectively

Answer (score 2):

The Black Bulls had gathered -31 stars due to destructive behaviour that caused their performance to be more harmful than the threat of the missions themselves.

https://blackclover.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Bull

Comment: but how did it compare with the others? were they the last?

Comment: yes, they were. Until the year Asta joined them. they became second

Answer (score 0):

Among the other squads, they were last place. Every year, they would get behind and stay behind. I think they were even in the negatives with their star count. It wasn’t until Asta joined and inspired the team to try harder did that change. They’re now sitting in 2nd place behind Yuno’s squad, the Golden Dawn.

If you mean strength among squad members, Yami was the strongest, probably followed by Henry (unknown at the time though), maybe Luck then Zora or Zora then Luck, Charmy, Magna, Gordon, Gauche, Vanessa, Grey, Noelle, and Finral before Asta joined.

Answer (score 0):

Black bulls especially known as Worst of the worst. This term also came as they were always last in the tournament. They only started getting points after the entry of Asta and Noelle. But they are more known for the bond of friendship that they all so cherish.

Truly they never really cared about the damn trophies.